# Why doesn't this data work with the Naïve Bayes algorithm?

Tags: weka, naivebayes, arff

[It is in ARFF format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0P8os.png). If you're not familiar with ARFF, it's basically that everything under the @data marker is in CSV.

For clarification, I am trying to use the dataset on Weka but the option to use Naïve Bayes is greyed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every classifier, clusterer, filter etc in Weka can only handle certain types of data, i.e., its **capabilities** (which you can check in GUI). These capabilities are then compared against the data. In case of a mismatch, the GUI won't allow you to apply the algorithm.

Long story short: the *dport* attribute is of type *string* which NaiveBayes can't handle. You can convert that attribute into a *nominal* one using the [StringToNominal](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/StringToNominal.html) filter.

Comment: This was the correct answer. Thanks, I don't currently have enough karma to upvote.

Comment: But you should br able to accept it as the right answer?